# Is it possible to profit from Sushi High Roller?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I enjoy making money, and I do Le Wow and the Battle Chateau. Then while exploring, I came across the 4th restaurant, Sushi High Roller. With the money I had, I went in there and completed a run, and I realized I lost over 100K. Is there any to get enough money to make more than 500K with the battles and the big gold nuggets?

Comment: Possibly with the Prize Money O-Power, although I haven't tried this.

Comment: I've heard that it is, barely, but unless you're RIGHT the noise, by 3 turns or less, Cafe Le Wow is better. And if you mess uip a lot, cafe le wow is ALWAYS superior.

Comment: Didn't you post an answer to my question regarding sushi high roller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**,

There is no way possible to come out of Sushi High Roller with a profit. Even with Max Style + Amulet Coin + Lvl 3 Prize Money O-Power the numbers run like this:

Entry Fee (With Max Style) = ***$450,000***

What you get:

Prize Money (With lvl-3 O-Power & Amulet Coin) = **$160,000**

Big Nuggets * 25(Best possible) = **$250,000**

Total winnings ~ **$410,000**

That is still a net loss of **-$40,000**. So Basically it is not worth going in there for money, unless you want a completionist record for starring all the battles, or the Exp.

There is no confirmation of the Entry Fee going any lower, for it to become profitable.

Comment: There is a new move called Happy Hour, currently known only by an event Inkay, which doubles prize money when used, in addition to the Amulet Coin (i.e. Happy Hour + Amulet Coin = 4x prize money). Seems like that would just about give you enough profit.

Comment: Great! When I get my hands on it I will change my answer!

Comment: The bounty will be yours in 4 hours, unless someone can get a better answer.

Answer (score -2):

Have you maybe thought about having one pokemon hold luck incense, and another with amulet coin, and then the o- power, you'd make like 750k

Comment: Amulet Coin "Does not stack with Luck Incense or other Amulet Coins." http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/In-battle_effect_item#Amulet_Coin